# How can I identify the CSS_Selector, Class, or Element from an object hidden in the HTML?

Tags: html, css-selectors, getelementbyid

I've been attempting to web scape some detail from the following website, but I'm unable to figure out how to access the class, id, and class type for the following object below.

```
https://mor.nlm.nih.gov/RxClass/search?query=H%7CATC1-4&searchBy=class&sourceIds=&drugSources=atc1-4%7Catc%2Cepc%7Cfdaspl%2Cmeshpa%7Cmesh%2Cdisease%7Cndfrt%2Cchem%7Cfdaspl%2Cmoa%7Cfdaspl%2Cpe%7Cfdaspl%2Cpk%7Cndfrt%2Cva%7Cndfrt%2Cdispos%7Csnomedct%2Cstruct%7Csnomedct
```

On the following website with the search condition you'll see in the center of the screen it

class: **SYSTEMIC HORMONAL PREPARATIONS, EXCL. SEX HORMONES AND INSULINS** / id: **H** / class type: **ATC1-4** / show context

I'd like to make the assumption that the above is in bold is a CSS_Selector, but I can't seem to locate it.

Any guidance on how to locate the class, element, or css_selector would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the developer console in Firefox or any Chromium-based browser: open the contextmenu on the element you want and select `Inspect`. Then the developer console should open. The current element should be focused in the DOM tree. There you should have the option `Copy > CSS selector`. And you're done. In your current case the path is something like this:

`html body div.container-fluid div.col-sm-9.col-sm-offset-3.col-md-9.col-md-offset-3.main div#tabContent.tab-content div#drugMemberPane.tab-pane.active div#drugMemberPage.table-responsive div.propText strong`

Comment: Ok, so if I did it correctly, then the id: A is defined as #drugMemberPage > div.propText > strong:nth-child(2) and By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.propText") gives the correct selector!  You are awesome Gregor, thank you!  I should of looked into how to use chrome dev tools first!

Comment: Now a follow up question, if I wanted to access each individual item in the div.container-fluid or css_selector div.PropText how would I go about finding the individual item.

Comment: You mean every `<strong />` element?

Comment: Yes, each strong element in the div.PropText there are 3

Comment: I guess `div.table-responsive div.propText strong` should do the job for you.

Comment: That sort of worked, I get all 3 in one, but to separate the id, class, and classtype I have to do in a data frame, which isn't an issue.  I was thinking they were separate, but they're strung together.  You've been a lot of help to me Gregor, thank you!

Comment: You can access them one by one with `div.table-responsive div.propText strong:nth-child($x)` where `$x` should be 1, 2, or 3.